# div not showing above text box

Tags: html, css

I want to show a search icon over the start of the a text input box.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<div id="search-icon"></div>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
```

And my CSS:

```
#search-icon {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#455a21;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    border:thin solid black;
    border-radius:30px;
    z-index:100;
}

input#search {
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
    left:-30px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:35px;
    border-radius:20px;
    border:thin solid #6d6e71;
    z-index:1;
}
```

It shows the div right where I want it, but below the actual text box. When I change the search icon position to absolute, it screws up my positioning.

How do I swop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it using relative position for both. But just change their z-index.

```
#search-icon {

background-color:#455a21;
height:60px;
width:60px;
border:thin solid black;
border-radius:30px;
z-index:100;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
}

input#search {
position:absolute;
top:15px;
left:30px;
padding:10px;
padding-left:35px;
border-radius:20px;
border:thin solid #6d6e71;
z-index:1;}​
```

is this what you are looking for [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TyVBp/6/)

Comment: as stated, position absolute screws up my positioning.

Comment: Look, it works when I put a separate div around it and style it from there, so I'm not saying it's wrong. Just with the current layout, it doesn't do what I want. Thanks for answering though! I always appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about having search-icon being on top of input#search?

Such as this: http://jsfiddle.net/52YfE/?

Comment: It doesn't work on Firefox and Chrome because of negative z-index value. It only works on Internet Explorer. -1 means it gets behind body element, therefor it can't get focus. You can set both elements `position` to `relative` and give higher `z-index` value to `#search-icon` like @agriboz 's updated answer.

Comment: Hey @DarkRanger, Erkan has a point.  Just ran it and the search box doesn't receive focus except in IE. I'm sorry for giving an improper answer (not too familiar with positioning except a tad more now).  If you want to, just shift the credit to agriboz due to his updated answer.  He's right about giving both div relative positions, and then a higher z-index to which you want in front.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want exactly but check it out this one http://jsfiddle.net/V8AZE/