# How to make the textbox above the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv9DM/2/).

I need to make the textbox to be displayed on the middle of the slider. The textbox should not get affected if hover.

I tried `z-index:999` But it didn't worked.

I saw the questions [div not showing above text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716709/div-not-showing-above-text-box)
 But it didn't helped me.

Here is my code :

html :

```
<div class="mask">
<h2>Hover Style #5</h2>
<p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
<a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
</div>
```

css :

```
.view-fifth:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
   -o-transform: translateX(300px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(300px);
   transform: translateX(300px);
}
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give position absolute for the input :

```
<input type='text' style="z-index:999;position: absolute;top: 50px;left: 67px;">
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Cv9DM/3/

Comment: posted it before me while I was fighting with "put some code before jsfiddle..." :)

Comment: Working as expected, Thank you so much.. !!.. But it is not working for if i place it in two slider. I will ask it in a seperate question.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to specify position:absolute. Without it "z-index" doesn't work.

Solve it like this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="above">
```

CSS

```
.above{
   z-index:999;
   position: absolute;
   left: 80px;
}
```

Or here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cv9DM/5/

Answer (score 1):

you can add  position: relative to de input.
This way it will keep where it was before

```
<input type='text' style="z-index:999; position: relative"/>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv9DM/16/)

Answer (score 0):

Provide position:absolute; in the text box  style