# Text box not in centered position for the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the continuation of my previous Question [How to make the textbox above the slider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24819064/3477716).

### The textbox needs to be displayed in the centre of both slider.

How can i do this ?

Here is the Jsfiddle that i have.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cv9DM/12/

css :

```
.view-fifth:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
   -o-transform: translateX(300px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(300px);
   transform: translateX(300px);
}
```

**Note : Make the Result Tab little wide to make the two slider visible in Horizontal**

The horizontalized screen is given below

[image]

### Edit : Expected output :

[image]

Comment: like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/Cv9DM/18/

Comment: check my answer, its what you want..

Comment: and what if the screen resolution will be small?

Comment: No, check the updated question

Comment: @Kheemapandy : No issue of the screen resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/Cv9DM/21/)

```
<div>
    <input type='text' style="z-index:999;position: absolute;
top: 70px;
left: 230px;">
<div class="view view-fifth">

<img src="http://s15.postimg.org/aranu1b5n/image.jpg" />
<div class="mask">
<h2>Hover Style #5</h2>
<p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
<a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="view view-fifth">
<img src="http://s15.postimg.org/aranu1b5n/image.jpg" />
<div class="mask">
<h2>Hover Style #5</h2>
<p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
<a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You changed only the top: 70px; left: 230px; ?

Comment: No i took a div at top in which i included your textbox and other two slider div's..

Comment: Thanks, i accepted an upvoted your answer. If you find my questions is valid, kindly upvote the quetsion too

Comment: @JaiKrish : sure why not.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv9DM/24/)

Changed CSS for input

```
<input type='text' style="z-index:999;position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -11px 0 0 -82px; width:160px; padding: 4px;">
```

added a `div` to wrap both the slides `.outer`

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    float: left
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question (the expected output), Kindly check it

Answer (score 1):

if you need to `input` box vertically center you can use this property. see the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv9DM/25/)**.

```
input[type="text"]{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index:1;
  position:fixed;
  left:18em;
 top:9em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your edit, you need to use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`.

```
 <div style="z-index:999;position: fixed; top: 50px; left:0; right:0; margin:0px auto;"><input type='text' /></div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv9DM/23/)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this one too
[with use of jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/vilaskumkar/BYbLw/)

```
<div class="view-ten clearfix">
    <input type='text' class='textbox' style="z-index:999;position: absolute;"/>
</div>
<div class="view view-fifth"></div>
<div class="view view-fifth"></div>
```